# How to create a three-by-three floating array in Arduino

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide, arduino-esp8266

I need a three-by-three array of flutes that should be in a loop (the loop can be used and should be displayed at the terminal output)
I found the following code on the internet but it only prints one type of one-dimensional floating data

```
template<class T> inline Print &operator <<(Print &obj, T arg) { obj.print(arg); return obj; }
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  int name = 1;
  int age = 3;
  Serial << "My name is " << name << " and I am " << age << " years old.";
  Serial.println();
  delay(500);
  String bob1 = "bob";
  Serial.println(bob1);
  delay(500);
  float f1 = 1.31;
  float f2 = 2.39;
  float f3 = 3.01;
  float arr[3] = { f1, f2, f3 };
  Serial << f1 << "  " << f2 << "  " << f3;
  Serial.println();
}
```

Comment: No. It does not print 1-dimensional array data. Print, println and the  `<<` operator always print single variables. `operator <<` can be chained, as you can see from its definition in your first code line.

Answer (score 0):

Below solution solved my problem

```
float ar[3][3][3] = {

{{5.6,1.7,2.6},// row 0
{3.4,9.9,2.2},
{8.3,3.7,3.2}},


 {{2.9,4.6,4.6},
  {2.5,4.5,4.2},
  {15,16,17}},

 {{8.7,8.9,5.7},
  {8.5,9.7,4.5},
  {4.7,2.8,9.7}}


};



void setup() {

Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() 
 
for (int i=0;i<3;i++){
  for (int j=0;j<3;j++){
    for(int k=0;k<3;k++){

  Serial.println(ar[i][j][k]);
  delay(500);
   }
  }
 }
}
```